# Can I use CSS to distort borders so they look like sketched?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have bordered boxes (`div`) which I want to make look like a sketch, i.e. with the borders not drawn as straight lines, but slightly distorted, as if drawn by hand.

Illustration:

[image: "Sketched" boxes]

Can this be done using CSS transformation or similar?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess you could just use an image.

Comment: [this](https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/NPXodB?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=0f42984c3ec4ac20d1cc2e31c059e0919a7f4af7-1595952474-0-Ad3NEmAmFdmUWK43rNjEZjXMuTvuXuy4uDxGXR3S3e6E8s4UcVljuajPorjUPbdSwTbNEoLbhh9rhKaYcNUSlX7PrzyWBXkk6HBciRZ7ltGwEjRPBxmJky2V8o2U0przLyEiIrbVepZtjLiP7Fhn3-goDBSBtZUbvJupPf6WZlWd1xuY0m8fYwBXnpSmj4K_tOkPAegUuwF5KqzpFogleFj2Bjww3vXSX1iy5rZ2w3gsZ5I-erSIC-g0HUrWBCgPY3zINbVQeudCQuTiDmq0l-TvOZU9LZizp1wtwokVjCcTGfz7jibqX7pOxUzJKr4l3U1xwXzFT8rdWyDepUfogqC2TTpNACq-pwv47ha81KeV) helped me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This article on [hand-drawn borders](https://codemyui.com/hand-drawn-border-buttons-css/) gives a great example of achieving this effect on buttons using only CSS by using large elliptical rounded corners (through the [CSS border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property). It probably won't work as well for large `div` elements.

Example adapted from the article:

```css
button {
      background:transparent;
      padding:0.5rem 0.5rem;
      margin:0 0.5rem;
      font-size:1rem;

      border-top-left-radius: 255px 15px;
      border-top-right-radius: 15px 225px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 225px 15px;
      border-bottom-left-radius:15px 255px;
}

button:hover{
   box-shadow:2px 8px 4px -6px hsla(0,0%,0%,.3);
}
button.lined.thick{
   border:solid 3px #41403E;
}
button.dotted.thick{
   border:dotted 3px #41403E;
}
button.dashed.thick{
  border:dashed 3px #41403E;
}
button.lined.thin{
   border:solid 2px #41403E;
}
button.dotted.thin{
   border:dotted 2px #41403E;
}
button.dashed.thin{
  border:dashed 2px #41403E;
}
```

```html
<button class='lined thick'>Lined Thick</button>
<button class='dotted thick'>Dotted Thick</button>
<button class='dashed thick'>Dashed Thick</button>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<button class='lined thin'>Lined Thin</button>
<button class='dotted thin'>Dotted Thin</button>
<button class='dashed thin'>Dashed Thin</button>
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. Despite the other one works too, this uses only css and avoid using images which fits better for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually a very nice solution and closer to what I was initially looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [CSS Border Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

[Here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image2) on w3schools website.

And here's a code example:

```
#borderimg {
    /* You can also use border-top or border-bottom to target the side you want affected */
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 50 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 50 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(border.png) 50 round;
}
```

Comment: I think the explanation at w3schools is not very good. I can recommend [this article](http://thenewcode.com/438/CSS-Border-Image-Explained) which gives a very detailed explanation. And [this site](http://border-image.com/) provides a very helpful tool to find the best values for border-image-slice and other properties.

Comment: @not2savvy I know what you mean, w3schools tend to be quite vague at times. But hey, they have a lot to do I guess.

Comment: You're probably right. Here's my implementation, just for reference: [Sketched box example](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fzipfly.de%2Fextimg%2Fsketchbox.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Afalse%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B4%2C4%2C4%2C3%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B44%2C47%2C58%2C50%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22round%22%2C%22stretch%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A0.3325143325143325%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D) (click *toggle style* to set light background)