# Creating Natural Edge with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an attractive strat column (geology).  I need to create several hundred of them, so maintaining uniformity begs for a CSS solution.

Below is a hand drawn version that has a nice, naturual edge on the left, versus my horrible attempt using CSS.

[image: Hand-drawn Strat Column]
[image: CSS attempt Strat Column]

Below is my code that I used to create the above computer version, though it is not working perfectly, as I don't have my hatches on a server (I am just running the HTML on my computer).

```css
#strat-pane { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
#strat-column { margin:30px auto; width:90px; }
.member { width:120px; border:1px solid black; position: relative; }
.member.slope:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: -1px; bottom: 0; right: -1px; width: 50%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%) 0 0/100% 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="strat-pane">
<div id="strat-column">
<div id="m1" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
<div id="m2" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
<div id="m3" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
<div id="m4" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Mi.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
<div id="m5" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
<div id="m6" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
<div id="m7" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
<div id="m8" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
<div id="m9" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
<div id="m10" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
<div id="m11" class="member ledge" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
<div id="m12" class="member slope" style="height: 30px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
<div id="m13" class="member ledge" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
<div id="m14" class="member slope" style="height: 75px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
<div id="m15" class="member ledge" style="height: 350px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: #e44539;"></div>
<div id="m16" class="member slope" style="height: 350px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: #de9b81;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an idea how to do it, but do not have the time to try it out. Basic idea would be to use
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use CSS to distort borders so they look like sketched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694588/can-i-use-css-to-distort-borders-so-they-look-like-sketched)

Comment: Css is the wrong option here. SVG is clearly the proper option.

Comment: If you're *really* after something to the level of imperfection as the graphic on the left, I'd try something in either canvas or SVG, rather than endlessly chiselling details into the CSS. A shortcut to this might be to use some graphing library like [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) and make a shaded line-chart on its side.

Comment: I am not sure I can see how a clip-path could create a natural look, it seems like it demands basic shapes (e.g. circles).  The border-image idea might be able to be stretched and altered to look more natural, I will look into that.  I love working with SVGs, but I'm not seeing how I could use an SVG in this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an SVG filter can get you closer and you don't need to change a lot in your code. I simply replaced the gradient trick with a `clip-path`

```css
#strat-pane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

#strat-column {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 90px;
}

.member {
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.slope {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 100%,80% 0);  
}
```

```html
<div id="strat-pane">
  <div id="strat-column">
    <div id="m1" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
    <div id="m2" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div id="m3" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
    <div id="m4" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Mi.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
    <div id="m5" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
    <div id="m6" class="member slope" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div id="m7" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
    <div id="m8" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
    <div id="m9" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ls.png&quot;); background-color: #eac896;"></div>
    <div id="m10" class="member slope" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
    <div id="m11" class="member ledge" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div id="m12" class="member slope" style="height: 30px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
    <div id="m13" class="member ledge" style="height: 15px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div id="m14" class="member slope" style="height: 75px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ms.png&quot;); background-color: #E46254;"></div>
    <div id="m15" class="member ledge" style="height: 350px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Cg.png&quot;); background-color: #e44539;"></div>
    <div id="m16" class="member slope" style="height: 350px; background-image: url(&quot;img/pngs/Ss.png&quot;); background-color: #de9b81;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 22 -15" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Termani.  The SVG clip-path is new to me.  Some very exciting possibilities there, thank you.  The matrix is new to me also, and I am not getting it very well.  It seems like it is smoothing the edge a bit.  Can you add a few words of explanation as to what the specific values you have chosen are doing?  That would help me be able to tweak it a bit to get the look I want.

Comment: @Thomas here is a detailed article about the effect: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/