# How to make advance shape of CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wonder that if someone could provide or suggest me how to make a css style better approach than mine?

This is what expected shape :

[image]

What is done so far :

```css
.labelModel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #404040;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.line-infocard {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #404040;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="line-infocard"></div>
  <div class="labelModel">info :</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited. Thanks your reminder.

Comment: so you want doodle-styled css border?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694588/can-i-use-css-to-distort-borders-so-they-look-like-sketched)

Comment: I want the container `div ` with class `labelModel` merged with `line-infocard`. So expected only one `div` wrapped the line and the box.

Comment: Do you have proper design? Now it's very unclear of what you want

Comment: I want div `labelModel` and `line-infocard` merge into one. And the shape expected as I mentioned above.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want one `<div></div>` providing both the `line-infocard` and `labelModel` using CSS. That cannot be done with just CSS styling the lines etc. If you want everything to work in one HTML DOM element, you will need to look at canvas drawing. @ArezouSaremian has done what is possible with the constraints you provided inserting it into one HTML DOM element by providing a wrapping `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.labelModel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.labelBox{
background-color: #404040;
width:89%;
height:89%;
padding: 10px;
transform: rotate(1deg);
color:orange;

}

.line-infocard {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  right:50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  z-index: 99;
  
  background-color: #404040;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.line-infocard::after{
content:'';
width:2px;
height:40px;
background-color:black;
top: 88%;
right: -11px;
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(
-28deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="line-infocard"></div>
  <div class="labelModel">
    <div class="labelBox">
      info :
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make `line-infocard` and `labelModel` become one div ?