# How can I create this hand drawn border in CSS for a button?

Tags: html, css

I've seen this question, which is actually good advice

[Can I use CSS to distort borders so they look like sketched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694588/can-i-use-css-to-distort-borders-so-they-look-like-sketched)

but my designer has given us something a little bit more crazy!

I cannot see how I can get a button's border to be like this. Should I just implement the entire thing as a div with background images?

Or maybe a VERY oval button, and just try to place the hand-drawn border as an image around the button?

[image: button states design]

I tried this which works, but it's not a very good solution since I'd have to adjust the position of the border every time we decide on different text in the button.

```
      const bgImageStyle = {
        width: '300px',
        height: '50px',
        backgroundImage: `url("/assets/purple-border.png")`,
        backgroundSize: '280px 40px',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: '0 10px',
      }

        <button style={bgImageStyle}
        >
          Get Started Right Now
        </button>
```

Comment: Absolutely go with an svg for this imho. [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) is a handy tool to sketch out some curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not much of a designer so I'm sure you can improve on my attempts.

I've created an ellipse with a break in it using an SVG with bezier curves using [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

I've then used the [URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) tool to convert it into a background-image url.

I've then played around with the `background-position` and `background-size` properties to position it. I'm sure if you fiddle about with it you'll make it look better than I did. Code below

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
}
.button {
  --ellipse-colour: #7D65FF;
  --text-colour: white;
  color:var(--text-colour);
  font-weight:700;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  width: fit-content;
  background-image: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0.1 0 8.6 2.9'%3E%3Cpath d='M 4.8 0.3 C 0 -0.6 -1.1 2 3.8 2.7 C 7.7 3.2 8.7 1.8 6.2 0.7' stroke='%23BEA3FF' stroke-width='0.2' fill='none'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"),
    radial-gradient(var(--ellipse-colour) 60%,transparent 63%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 115% 100%,auto;
  background-position:20% 50%;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.button:hover {
  --ellipse-colour: #EEECF9;
  --text-colour: #7E66FF;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>Get Started</div>
```

Here's a version using the ::before pseudo element to overlay an ellipse using mask to show the content below. The gap in the line is added using conic-gradient.

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  --ellipse-colour: #7D65FF;
  --text-colour: white;
  --line-colour: #BEA3FE;
  color:var(--text-colour);
  font-weight:700;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  width: fit-content;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(var(--ellipse-colour) 60%,transparent 63%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 500ms;
  --angle: 6deg;
}
.button::before {
  margin:0rem 0.4rem;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  inset:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(transparent 63%, white 65%);
  mask: radial-gradient(transparent 63%, white 65%);
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  background-image: conic-gradient(var(--line-colour) 50deg, transparent 50deg, transparent 70deg, var(--line-colour) 70deg);
  transition:transform 1000ms;
}


.button:hover {
  --ellipse-colour: #EEECF9;
  --text-colour: #7E66FF;
  --line-colour: #7D66FF;
  --angle:0deg;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>Get Started and things</div>
```